# Is this true that ${\left| {{{(Ax)}^*}(By)} \right|^2} \le {(Ax)^*}(Ax).{(By)^*}(By)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B\in M_n$  and $x\in C^n$.

Is this true that

${\left| {{{(Ax)}^*}(By)} \right|^2} \le {(Ax)^*}(Ax).{(By)^*}(By)$?

Comment: Have you heard of Cauchy Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: what about $y$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: And in the notation of the link, $\langle v,u \rangle = u^* . v$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
f(\lambda)=(Ax+\lambda By)\cdot(Ax+\lambda By)^*, \quad\lambda\in\mathbb R.
$$
Then
$$
f(\lambda)=(By)\cdot(By)^*\lambda^2+2 (By)\cdot(Ax)^*\lambda+(Ax)\cdot(Ax)^*\ge 0.
$$
This means that the discriminant $\Delta=\big(2 (By)\cdot(Ax)^*\big)^2-4(Ax)\cdot(Ax)^*(By)\cdot(By)^*$
of the quadratic form is non-positive.